# Retrieving all elements matching criteria in array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter

I have a dataframe that I am trying to process in Jupyter. This dataframe is originally filled with `NaN` where blanks are found, but I then decided to replace them with 'Null' strings (since I was having problems ignoring the `NaN`).

The following code is a sample of the original file `mydata.txt`

```
##IGNORE THIS LINE
group2,"BLA","BLE","BLI","BLO","BLU","TAT","TET","TOT","TUT"
group0,"BLA","BLE","BLI","BLO","BLU"
group3,"BLA","BLE","BLI"
```

The idea is to build arrays where all elements that are not `NaN` (or later, 'Null') that I can feed to filter somewhere else.

```
import rpy2.ipython
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import re #python for regex
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R

path='C:/MyPath/'

allgroups=pd.read_csv(path+'mydata.txt',sep=",",skiprows=1,header=None,index_col=0)
allgroups=allgroups.fillna("Null")

def groupdat(groupname):
    #Cleans group
    precleaned=numpy.array(allgroups.loc[[groupname]])
#     matching = [s for s in precleaned if s != "Null" ] #I tried this
    matching=filter(lambda elem: elem != "Null",precleaned) #I also tried this.
    print(matching)
    return

groupdat('group0')
```

Both `matching` commented above yield an error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

The output of `precleaned` is

```
[['BLA' 'BLE' 'BLI' 'BLO' 'BLU' 'Null' 'Null' 'Null' 'Null']]
```

Printing `allgroups.loc[[groupname]]` gives

```
          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
0                                                                  
group0    BLA   BLE   BLI   BLO   BLU   Null  Null  Null  Null

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

I appreciate all feedback.

Comment: your suggestion yields `[['BLA' 'BLE' 'BLI' 'BLO' 'BLU' 'Null' 'Null' 'Null' 'Null']]`. What am I doing wrong if there are too many dimensions?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you so much for your help. I had added the output of that print to the original post

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no worries, I really appreciate for your help. I have added a sample in the original post. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have one dimension too much when you create your array

```
numpy.array(allgroups.loc[["group0"]])
```

So the listcomp/`filter` iterates on the sole element, which is an array, hence the message you're getting

create it like this:

```
numpy.array(allgroups.loc[["group0"][0]])
```

then `[s for s in precleaned if s != "Null" ]` yields:

```
['BLA', 'BLE', 'BLI', 'BLO', 'BLU']
```

as expected.